# One word for "fierce passion"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for one single word to replace the phrase *fierce passion*. The entire sentence is:

> I found in myself a **fierce passion** to understand the language of man.

Comment: [Passion](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/passion) is plenty fierce all on its very own.

Comment: Did you really find [all these](http://thesaurus.com/browse/passion?s=t) unacceptable?

Comment: I found enough of them unacceptable to need other options. The text I'm working on has a very specific style to it.

Comment: Any of the synonyms for [zeal](http://thesaurus.com/browse/zeal)

Comment: @faerubin: Your remark makes it sound like you had already examined those synonyms. If that's the case, you should elaborate more on what's wrong with some of the leading candidates. Otherwise, this becomes nothing more than a guessing game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Obsession*, *zeal*, or *drive* would work well in this particular usage.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest **ardour**, given its [etymon](http://thefreedictionary.com/ardour) *ārdēre*, which means "to burn". It works well if you are to use it appropriately in the sense of burning desire or passion.

Comment: +1 for "burning desire" which would have been my suggestion! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider *compulsion* or *fixated*, although the sentence might require minor structural modifications.  For example, you could write "I found myself **compelled** to understand the language of man" or something similar.